# Parse Platform - Check the "value" of a "key" that is contained within an array of objects

Tags: android, ios, arrays, json, parse-platform

Given a Parse object that has a field of type "Array" with the following array elements with the following key:value pairs in them:

```
[
  {
    "aa": "00",
    "bb": "11",
    "cc": "closed",
    "dd": "33"
  },
 {
    "aa": "01",
    "bb": "11a",
    "cc": "open", 
    "dd": "33a"
  }
....
]
```

(The values in the `cc` key will always be  `open/closed/disabled`.)

How would I check that the array element with key/value `"aa" : "01"` has its `"cc"` key's value set to `open` (or whatever specific value I'm searching for)?

During my research, an answer on another site made a reference to creating a new class of objects, while also using an array of Pointers. But I did not understand it much. Would that be more efficient?

Comment: you might want to loop your array and check of the cc value everything , since looping will allow you to loop each position of the array

Comment: You can create array of objects, the object will have aa,bb,cc,dd as members, and then iterate and find cc for each aa